# Use StackOverflow colors on Super User (or any other "trilogy" site)

Tags: feature-request, design

I occasionally use some of the other "trilogy" sites like SuperUser, but find the themes very distracting. I actually do like the SO theme the best, and since I use that the most, I would prefer having that look on all the other trinity sites. I would request a feature added to your user profile where you could select your CSS theme you prefer for the site you are on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really shouldn't be any reason why you shouldn't be able choose from any of the various themes.  Done right thematic elements would be localized in their own CSS file and it would simply be a matter of switching which CSS file gets loaded.  It's even possible, using cookies, to do this without requiring any schema mods.

See the jQuery [theme switcher](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/ThemeSwitcher) widget for ideas.

Comment: Or use a sane browser with user style sheets.

Comment: I'm a little ambivalent about user style sheets.   Letting users muck up my interface in ways that might just break it is not, as a developer, an altogether wonderful thing.

Comment: @tvanfosson: but to me, as a user, is a great thing not to be attached to what the developer thinks I should be seeing. Of course, if it breaks it's my fault.

Comment: @voyager -- and I'm sure that you won't complain to the help desk at all about my app when that happens, either.  ;-)

Comment: FWIW - I'm actually putting this into practice: http://launchpad.uiowa.edu.

Comment: I  won't call to the help desk *searches for personal cell phone number*

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this can be accomplished via greasemonkey, and I suspect that some browsers may allow you to theme the website with a custom CSS without a greasemonkey script.

However, Jeff and Joel are big on branding and user confusion issues, so I doubt they'll make this a built in feature.

When you prepare to ask a question on SU, you *know* you're not on SO...

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, though, if you're simply allowed to choose your own theme.  Obviously, if you've changed it you ought to know about it and not be confused by it.

Comment: It's fine to have them be different *by default*... but I find it overly paternalistic to "save" the user from confusion when they are the ones *requesting* "to be confused". I think its perfectly reasonable to set a "good" default of having them look different, with the option of allowing the user to change it. 

I suspect all the sites use a good CSS hierarchy to do the theming, so the work should not be difficult at all.

Comment: It is reasonable for a company to force a thematic element or style on visitors to their website for branding purposes though.  Since you can handle it on your end, then why make it easy for users to break the brand identity?

Comment: @tvanfossen: you obviously have much more confidence in the average computer user than i do. :)

Comment: @Kip - Let's not forget though... the sites are geared towards "average computer users". It's for programmers, sys admins and "super users". Granted, some people who claim to be super users really aren't ;) ... but you get my point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Greasemonkey script to do this, look at [this post by Jonathan Sampson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/want-to-browse-meta-with-the-upcoming-superuser-stylesheet-logo). Just before SU launched, he wrote that script to view MSO using the SU CSS. If you're a little familiar with Javascript you can easily modify it to view S[FU] using the SO color scheme.